# Will my skills improve when I make them Legendary?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Will my skills become stronger when I make them Legendary?

Comment: Hi Amir, even though I get what you mean, this question is incredibly vague, and usually these types of questions get downvoted. Can you explain in more detail what you mean, how you arrived at this problem, and maybe put in words what you expect based on what you've found so far?

Comment: @Joachim None of that matters, this question simply doesn't show any research whatsoever.

Comment: @Wrigglenite That's my point, rephrasing it for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your skill won't become stronger if you make them legendary. In fact, it will be even weaker, because its level will be reseted, and its efficiency is based on its level.

Moreover, all the skill points you spent on that one will be removed from its tree, but they will be available for spending on somewhere else.

In simple, your skill will be the same as the beginning of the game.

The main interests to make legendary a skill are:

- to be able to exceed the old level cap of 81...
- ...and so to gain more skill points to spend.

Comment: It helps to make sure whatever skill you reset is not ultra important OR can be leveled fast. I reset my One-Handed skill on my character that uses War Axes. I struggled a while to get back up.